# Sync of Local data to Live

Tags: android

Objective:App should work in Local and Live database or Auto sync when WI-FI enabled

I have 3 text fields:Name, Father name, Mother name

1. I want to save these text fields data into local database with out WIFI
2. Step 1: when internet is connected,they should be automatically uploaded to cloud database.

How can i achieve this using android?

[image]

Comment: Create a service for checking internet connection in your app, when service says Internet is available call upload method to upload data in cloud database.

Comment: When you click on  submit button first check internet connection. if internet connected then call api for sync data on server otherwise store your data into sqlite database.

myapplication file put method for notify when internet connect .
on connect method check sqlite database there is data that are not sync? that data upload on server.

Comment: URL: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sync-sqlite-database-with-server/

I followed this(URL) tutorial to do synchronize between sqlite databasae and web server.
But inserted data again inserted when internet connection on/off.So how to check whether the local data already inserted or not.

Comment: @VeerababuZonup Maintain flag in the local database. If a value is true then don't need to upload value and false then remain to upload so process that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) if you want to do it the easy way. This takes care of data being persisted and managed both online and offline.

There are other options too. You can always save database yourself locally, then manually sync with the server both while offline and online. But it is a lot cumbersome to do it than using some service like firebase or etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) to meet your goal.

Solution for your problem:
Extend `Worker`class and Implement `doWork()`.

```
public class SyncWorker extends Worker {
    //...
    public WorkerResult doWork() {
        String name = getInputData().getString("name", null);
        String fatherName = getInputData().getString("father_name", null);
        String motherName = getInputData().getString("mother_name", null);
        //Post data to your server.
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And add this worker to `WorkManager` like this.

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType
        .CONNECTED).build();
Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
            .putString("name", "XXX")
            .putString("father_name", "XXX's Father")
            .putString("mother_name", "XXX's Mother")
            .build();

OneTimeWorkRequest uploadWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints).setInputData(inputData).build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWork);
```

WorkManager will take care of persisting your input data and calling `SyncWorker::doWork` function when internet connection is available.

Comment: It's not working for me.In my program Using BroadcastReceiver it's knowing whether the internet available or not.Based on status i am getting the  data insert to database.But in my case Its inserting twice when internet connection on/off.